# How to display data set with data point in core plot?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-plot

I want to display data set with data point in core plot. For example graph is plotting (1,2), (2,4), (4,8) etc on core plot then it should also display these points on graph.

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have u see example is core plot?There are some sample example in that folder.Among them u shall find CorePlotGallery.
Here you find the full folder
http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/downloads/detail?name=CorePlot_0.9.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: have u found something ??There are lot of examples have done.